# In android, my app is working on less than ApI 21 devices, but on APi 21 devices giving an error

Tags: android

I created 2 virtual devices(one lollipop(api 21)) and other(kitkat(api19)). When I try to run my application, it loads fine in the kitkat, but gives an error and closes in api21. I tried on devices too and the same happens. I've pasted the error log here...does anyone know what to do?Please help!!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appingapps.narayan.mancalapp/com.appingapps.narayan.mancalapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360).....


Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)..............

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)....

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 36009012 byte allocation with 524288 free bytes and 31MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method).........
```

below is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/profileBButton"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_pic_ring"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/profileB"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profileBButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileBButton"/>
<ImageButton
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/volume"
    android:src="@drawable/yesvolume"
    android:onClick="setVolume"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<ImageButton
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/volume"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/volume"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/music"
    android:src="@drawable/music"
    android:onClick="setMusic"/>


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/blueButton7"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/kb0"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profileBButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profileBButton"/>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/blueButton6"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/b0"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueButton7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueButton7"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blueButton7" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/blueButton5"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/b0"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueButton6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueButton6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blueButton6" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/blueButton4"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/b0"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueButton5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueButton5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blueButton5" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/blueButton3"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/b0"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueButton4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueButton4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blueButton4" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/blueButton2"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/b0"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueButton3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueButton3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blueButton3" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/blueButton1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/b0"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueButton2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueButton2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blueButton2" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/redButton1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/r0"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blueButton7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueButton7"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blueButton7"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/redButton2"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/r0"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/redButton1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redButton1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/redButton1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/redButton3"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/r0"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/redButton2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueButton4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blueButton4" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/redButton4"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/r0"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/redButton3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueButton3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blueButton3" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/redButton5"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/r0"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/redButton4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redButton4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/redButton4" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/redButton6"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerPlay"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/r0"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/redButton5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redButton5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/redButton5" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/redButton7"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/kb0"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueButton7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blueButton7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redButton6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blueButton1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/profileAButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/profileAButton"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lfarrow"
    android:src="@drawable/animel"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bText1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bText5"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rtarrow"
    android:src="@drawable/anime"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rText5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rText1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/rText1"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/redButton1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redButton1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/rText2"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/redButton2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redButton2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/rText3"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/redButton3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redButton3"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/rText4"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/redButton4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redButton4"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/rText5"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/redButton5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redButton5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/rText6"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/redButton6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redButton6"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/rText7"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/redButton7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/redButton7"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/redButton7"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/bText1"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/blueButton1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueButton1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blueButton1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileBButton"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/bText2"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/blueButton2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueButton2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blueButton2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileBButton"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/bText3"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/blueButton3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueButton3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blueButton3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileBButton"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/bText4"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/blueButton4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueButton4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blueButton4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileBButton"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/bText5"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/blueButton5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueButton5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blueButton5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileBButton"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/bText6"
    android:background="@drawable/score_ring"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/blueButton6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueButton6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blueButton6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileBButton"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/bText7"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/blueButton7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/blueButton7"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/blueButton7"/>

<ImageButton
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="@string/options"
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/homealt"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="getOptions"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="INFO"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/blueButton1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/blueButton1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/profileAButton"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_pic_ring"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/profileA"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileAButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/profileAButton"/>
```

Comment: It is an Inflate-Exception. You should post your XML

Comment: `Failed to allocate a 36009012 byte allocation with 524288 free bytes and 31MB until OOM`

Whatever you're allocating here is too large.

Comment: but works fine on Api19 and less

Comment: resolution of the images you load?

Comment: I don't know based on the xml, but if I had to guess one or all of your images are extremely large.  The inflater has to allocate them and resize them to fit inside the Views.  It looks like you're loading a few dozen images all at once which seems to add up to about 31MB.  You need to either resize the images or dynamically set the images with a single Bitmap  reference.

Comment: The physical devices you tested - are they different? What device ran KitKat and what device ran Lollipop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you have a large image (or more of them) which is in one of the drawable folders for lower density screens (like `drawable`) so when you run your app on a high density screen android upscales your already big image to a huge resolution and tries to allocate a large amount of memory for it. If that is the case you only need to move the image to a more appropriate folder, like `drawable-xxhdpi`.